# Using SUM() with multiple tables in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that will use the sum function to add up all values in 1 column then divide by the count of tuples in another table.  For some reason when i run the sum query by itself i get the correct number back but when i use it in my query below the value is wrong.

this is what im trying to do but the numbers are coming out wrong.

```
select (sum(adonated) / count(p.pid)) as "Amount donated per Child"
from tsponsors s, player p;
```

I found out the issue is in the sum. below returns 650,000 when it should return 25000

```
select (sum(adonated)) as "Amount donated per Child"
from tsponsors s, player p;
```

if i remove the from player p it gets the correct amount.  However i need the player table to get the number of players.

I have 3 tables that are related to this query.
player(pid, tid(fk))
team(tid)
tsponsors(tid(fk), adonated, sid(fk))  this is a joining table

what i want to get is the sum of all the amounts donated to each team sum(adonated) and divide this by the number of players in the database count(pid).

Comment: Assuming tables `tsponsors` and `player` are linked in some way, you need to put that into your query. For example: `WHERE s.playerID=p.playerID`

Comment: Table structure would help: in addition when doing sums for values which are in one to many relationships must be done before the join otherwise you end up with inflated/deflated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your sponsors are giving amounts to teams. You then want to know the proportion of donations per child in the sponsored team.

You would then need something like this:

```
SELECT p.tid,(SUM(COALESCE(s.adonated,0)) / COUNT(p.pid)) AS "Amount donated per Child"
FROM player p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tsponsors s ON s.tid=p.tid
GROUP BY p.tid
```

I also used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in order to show 0$ if a team has no sponsors.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect I didnt need the outer join though since all teams must have a sponsor.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select sum(s.adonated) / (SELECT count(p.pid) FROM player p) 
 as "Amount donated per Child"
from tsponsors s;
```

Your original query joins 2 tables without any condition, which results in cross join.

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT ts.tid, SUM(ts.adonated),num_plyr
FROM tsponsors ts 
INNER JOIN 
 (
   SELECT tid, COUNT(pid) as num_plyr
   FROM player
   GROUP BY tid
)a ON (a.tid = ts.tid)
GROUP BY ts.tid,num_plyr
```

Comment: orginally i had select                                            (sum(adonated)) as "Amount donated per Child"
from tsponsors s, player p, team t
where s.tid = t.tid and t.tid = p.tid;

Comment: my tables are organized where teams contain many players and teams have many sponsors.  So i tried joining on the player's team tid with teams tid and teams tid with sponsors tid. still got me an inflated number i think im doing the join wrong.

Comment: @Jeremy: Then I believe you need to put table structure in your question and what you want to achieve. It's impossible to guess what you had initially unless you say it...

Comment: i added the structure of the tables how they are linked and what i want from my query.

Comment: the above query doesnt work i get an error saying not a single-group group function.